# How can I change the background color of the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-effects

I want to `remove/change` the background color of an image in Matlab.

Anyone know how to do this?

Here is an example image, I want to remove the green background color.

[image]
<sub>(source: [frip.in](http://cdn4.frip.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/custom-widget-area-for-wordpress.jpg))</sub>

Comment: do you know what color the background is?

Comment: No, I don't know. As there are different cases, some of them maybe green background color and some maybe others. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: BTW, the background color maybe slightly different between different areas. Like the image shown above, some area are lighter green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest answer would be,

```
c = [70 100 70];
thresh = 50;
A = imread('image.jpg');
B = zeros(size(A));
Ar = A(:,:,1);
Ag = A(:,:,2);
Ab = A(:,:,3);
Br = B(:,:,1);
Bg = B(:,:,2);
Bb = B(:,:,3);
logmap = (Ar > (c(1) - thresh)).*(Ar < (c(1) + thresh)).*...
         (Ag > (c(2) - thresh)).*(Ag < (c(2) + thresh)).*...
         (Ab > (c(3) - thresh)).*(Ab < (c(3) + thresh));
Ar(logmap == 1) = Br(logmap == 1);
Ag(logmap == 1) = Bg(logmap == 1); 
Ab(logmap == 1) = Bb(logmap == 1);
A = cat(3 ,Ar,Ag,Ab);
imshow(A);
```

[image]

You should change `c` (background color) and `thresh` (threshold for `c`) and find the best that fits your background.

You can define `B` as your new background image. Fr example adding `Bb(:,:) = 255;`will give you a blue background.

[image]

You can even define `B` as an image.

In order to detect background you could find the color that is most used in the image, but that is not necessarily background I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is C and thresh? Based on what rules to change these two value for other images?  Thank you very much!

Comment: c is the definition of the green color (define on [R G B] with a value from 0 to 255). Thresh is your threshold which define the separation between what in green and what is not.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! Is there a way to change the color if we don't know what is the background color beforehand as there will be many images with different background color? Or just remove the background color?

Comment: @Kim you can find the default background of an image by analyzing the histogram of you three RGB layers.

Comment: @R.Bergamote. one example code about finding the default background color of an image?  Thanks

Comment: @R.Bergamote do you know how to find the default background color? Thanks!